# What are the full-names of NIO and BIO

Tags: java

What are the full-names of NIO and BIO? Please give the official documentation.

NIO: non-bloking I/O
BIO: Bloking I/O

or

NIO: New I/O
BIO: Basic I/O

Answer (score 1):

NIO is New I/O, it supports both blocking and non-blocking I/O.